# How to render new image when available in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a situation right now with my RN app, and I don't know how to tackle it.
I'm logging the user in through Facebook API, in our backend, we handle all the FB user data, and also, its profile picture that we crop to a certain size for performance purposes.
To do this, we run an async worker that will do the cropping, in the meantime, in the app we show a default user avatar with the app logo. But once the worker finished the task, the image isn't updated, not until I re-render the view, this re-render causes to run again "renderUserAvatar()" function which validates if the user has a profile picture or not. Which makes sense.

Now here's the help, how can I listen to this URL availability? So that whenever the Image is available, it re-renders?

At first, I thought about adding something like handling the Image's onError, by setting a setInterval, and trying to force a re-render, but that doesn't look very performant it rather sounds ugly.

Is there a clean way to handle this specific case-scenario?

This is my current renderUserAvatar function:

```
    renderUserAvatar() {
        const { userInfo } = this.props;
        if (!_.isEmpty(userInfo) && userInfo.userPictures && userInfo.userPictures.length) {
            const avatar = userInfo.userPictures.filter(pic => pic.isAvatar && pic.isEnabled);

            if (avatar && avatar.length) {
                const url = `${avatar[0].url}?height=${USER_AVATAR_HEIGHT}&width=${USER_AVATAR_WIDTH}`;
                return <Thumbnail large style={ styles.userProfilePic } source={{uri: url}}/>;
            }
        }

        return <Thumbnail large style={ styles.userProfilePic } source={ImageAssets['user-avatar']}/>
    }
```

(Thumbnail is a NativeBase's component based on React-Native Image. So it would have all the Image methods and props too)

Comment: Have you tried with a suspense component ?

Comment: No, i've never used Suspense. Do you have any example applied to images? you mean like Lazy.load?

Answer (score 0):

You could put your image into a state-variable.
At the first load (or if User-Image are not yet fetched) it is your Placeholder-Image.

If the async function runs on entering the screen and the images was fetched, replace the placeholder-image in the state with your new one.

The change of a state-variable will cause a re-render and this way, you'r image should appear.

Comment: Thing is, this async worker runs on backend, not on frontend. So I don't have a way to know when the worker has finished. Unless i work with the onLoad, onError, onLoadEnd callbacks. Could that work somehow? Thanks for replying btw!

Comment: What means backend? Seems you mixed up some stuff?! The RN-App has a state. Where ever you fetch your data is not important at all. If the data is received, and you  change the state with the received data, the state is changed, and the Screen will re-render. Sorry, I don't get, what exactly you mean if you talk about onLoad, onError and such stuff.

Comment: I might not be explaining the situation correctly. How can I change a state if i'm not making a direct call to backend to retrieve the image? It's just a sourceURI within a Thumbnail component. I'm not calling any endpoint for this. I understand what you say about changing the state to force a re-render, and i totally agree, that's the only way, but when will i change the state? Based on what? I don't have any callback when the image is created hence set to the userInfo to actually trigger a re-render.

Comment: The onLoad, onLoadEnd and onError are Image/Thumbnail callback props. I can try to work around that.

Comment: I know what's happening. I will have to re-think the way i'm doing this for a bit. I'll be back whenever I solved it. Thanks for trying to help, tho.

Comment: Ah, ok, maybe I see what you mean now. So why don't you make your live easy and use the crop-function directly in your device: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imageeditor ?

Comment: Yea, sounds awesome, but we wanted to reduce the request size, it seems that first downloads the image by URI, then crops it, and returns the cropped image in the success callback. Pretty cool but, we wanted to make faster request load times. Unless i'm reading the docs wrong.

Comment: I'll tell my backend friend to serve me the original facebook avatar picture no matter what, while the task is running, whenever it finishes, it will update to the cropped version one. And that will solve it.